# Vertical menu with vertical text

Tags: css, stylesheet, styles, styling

I need a vertical menu with vertical text in it.

Here is the link to working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyxuD/4/embedded/result/

You can edit it on jsfiddle site.

How to make it work in Firefox and IE?

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#TabStrip-1">Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#TabStrip-2">Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#TabStrip-3">Very long text...</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: By my reckoning it should work in Firefox **and** IE... I mean you have the Microsoft filter there and the -moz-transform attribute. I have never even heard of any of these attributes, but I would suggest looking up html / css transform tutorials on Google. Find one with a demo which works on both Firefox and IE, use it but change it to suit your needs.

Comment: Incidentally, rather than telling us to save your code as a webpage, you might be better of posting a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo and directing us to that (as well as reproducing the relevant code here).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about it.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy - yes, it has everything, but it still has to be styled.

Comment: a small mistake, should be -webkit-transform

Answer (score 0):

Vertical text? Like this:

V
e
r
t
i
c
a
l
?

I recently altered sIFR font replacement to do that for me and it worked quite well - if Flash and Javascript are acceptable in your case?

Comment: Can you point to an example how to use sIFR font replacement?

Comment: No. Follow the link you will see an example.

Comment: Hrm, sorry, I didn't check in IE/FF but Chrome without thinking - Chrome makes it look like a standard horizontal menu :/ Now looking in your specified browsers and it is very cool. sIFR here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Inman_Flash_Replacement, though it doesn't support vertical text - you'd have to either tweak the actionscript file yourself, or let me put up a link for you tomorrow if you like. Er, second - better link is: http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr

Comment: Thanks, probably I'll use just CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting css trick. I tested in my firefox, the menu is vertical and so the text, but it looks the position mess up.

after my survey, I found that when the "li" element rotates, the axis is at the middle of it, neither left side nor right side. So that is the reason why position mess up, because before rotation, the "li" elements align left but their width are different.

I rewrite some of your css and now the position looks better, but I think it's not the best practice.

```
ul
{
  float: left;         
  list-style: none;   
  padding: 0;
  margin-left: 40px;     
}

li
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -85px;
  margin-top: 45px;
  width: 120px;
  border: 1px solid #A7BAC5;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);     
  -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);                 
}
```